# Trying to do bisection method for input polynomial, stuck in forever loop

Tags: java

I feel like my code is right but every time I run it, nothing is printed out. Am I missing something? Also, I am wondering how to make the program stop once it finds all roots of a polynomial up to 5 exponents. Would I just make an array that holds 5 different values?

```
public void bisection(){
    this.x = 5;
    this.y = calculateY(5);

    while(this.y != 0) {
        if (this.y < 0) {
            this.lowerBound = x;
            while (this.y <= 0) {
                x--;
                if (this.y < lowerBound) {
                    x++;
                }
                if (this.y > 0) {
                    this.upperBound = x;
                }
            }
            double average = this.lowerBound + this.upperBound / 2;
            this.y = calculateY(average);
            if(this.y == 0){
                System.out.println(average);
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
        if(this.y > 0) {
            this.upperBound = x;
            while(this.y >= 0) {
                x--;
                if(this.y > upperBound) {
                    x++;
                }
                if(this.y < 0) {
                    this.lowerBound = x;
                }
            }
            double average = this.lowerBound + this.upperBound / 2;
            this.y = calculateY(average);
            if(this.y == 0){
                System.out.println(average);
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Assuming your types are doubles here, it is very unlikely that `y` will ever be *exactly* zero. You should maybe stop once it drops below some appropriate threshold (e.g. `abs(y) < 1e-6`).

Comment: Also: your `average` value is not really the average of `lower` and `upper`. I think you're missing parentheses (or a ` / 2` after `this.lowerBound`).

Comment: So should I check if this.y == 0.0 instead of just this.y == 0? is 0.0 and 0 different in java?

Comment: Well, no, because `y == 0.0` and `y == 0` are semantically identical. Maybe use the suggestion in the first comment.

Comment: Hm I abs is a good idea. I tried it and moved my block of code underneath each inner while inside the inner while. Also got rid of return;. Still stuck in forever loop. Must be the logic?

Comment: There are many, many problems in your logic - not least that you're not even doing bisection.

Answer (score 2):

In your innermost `while` loops:

```
while (this.y <= 0) {
```

and

```
while(this.y >= 0) {
```

nothing changes `this.y` - so these loops would never exit once entered.

Answer (score 1):

additionally to @Andy Turner's answer, the outer `while` makes no sense either, it will run only once:

```
while(this.y != 0) {
```

Stops as soon as `y == 0`

```
    if (this.y < 0) {
[... inifinite loop cut off ...]
        this.y = calculateY(average);
        if(this.y == 0){
            System.out.println(average);
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

The upper `if` will either print and terminate (`y==0`) or it will hard exit the function with the `return`. In either case, you will not have a chance to run a second loop in your outer `while`.

```
    if(this.y > 0) {
[ ... infinite loop2 cut off ... ]
        this.y = calculateY(average);
        if(this.y == 0){
            System.out.println(average);
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

The lower `if` will either print and terminate (`y==0`) or it will hard exit the function with the `return`. In either case, you will not have a chance to run a second loop in your outer `while`.

So, the outer `while` is actually an `if(y != 0)`.